# Provide 'catchError'

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I wanted to convert my app into flutter web, but when I tried to run it locally I get the following error

> An exception was throw by _MapStream listened by
>   StreamProvider, but no `catchError` was provided.
>
> Exception: NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'providerId'

I would appreciate some advice on how to resolve this.

Here's my main.dart file, in case it is relevant:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {   
  @override   
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return StreamProvider<User>.value(
       value: AuthService().user,
       child: MaterialApp(
         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
         theme: ThemeData(
           primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
         ),
         home: Wrapper(),
       ),
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your real problem is: NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'providerId'

Comment: I'm not sure how to resolve that. The app runs without problem on android and iOS and I am very unfamiliar with flutter web. Would appreciate if you could provide more guidance.

Comment: You need to post more source code

Comment: Are you following The Net Ninja tutorial? Because I have the same problem. I was able to make it work using StreamBuilder instead of a StreamProvider. But I like the StreamProvider solution better.

Comment: @AndreCytryn sorry for not getting back earlier. You are right, I was following the Net Ninja tutorial! Would you mind sharing how you used StreamBuilder instead of StreamProvider to over the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So my first solution was to use StreamBuilder instead of a StreamProvider:

```dart
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: AuthService().currentUser,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return AdminDashboardScreen();
    } else {
      return SignInScreen();
    }
  },
);
```

But now I have managed to make the StreamProvider work too! I found that there are a lot of Firebase packages out there... the one you should be using for web is this:
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase

But instead of importing and using as a class, you should be able to reference it like:

```dart
  import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;

  final fb.Auth _firebaseAuth = fb.auth();

  // create user object based on firebase user
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(fb.User user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get currentUser {
    return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  // sign in anon
  Future<User> signInAnon() async {
    try {
      fb.UserCredential result = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
      fb.User user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print('[AuthService] error signInAnon: ${e.toString()}');
      return null;
    }
  }
```